# Canonical Implementation of a Subclass of NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, ios, osx

I would like to develop a kind of template or canonical implementation for a concurrent subclass of `NSOperation`.

**Edit:** there is a related request which implements the [NSOperation subclass in Swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107659/canonical-implementation-for-a-concurrent-subclass-of-nsoperation-in-swift-2).

#### Requirements:

- Thread safe API.
- `start` shall only start the task once, otherwise it has no effect.
- The NSOperation object shall be immortal while the task is executing.

#### References:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

---

#### Solution

So far, I came up with this solution:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/**
 Canonical, Concurrent Subclass of NSOperation
 */

typedef void (^completion_block_t)(id result);

@interface MyOperation : NSOperation

// Designated Initializer
// For the sake of testing, parameter count equals the duration in 1/10 seconds until the task is fininshed.
- (id)initWithCount:(int)count completion:(completion_block_t)completioHandler;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) id result;
@property (nonatomic, copy) completion_block_t completionHandler;
@end

@implementation MyOperation {
    BOOL _isExecuting;
    BOOL _isFinished;
    
    dispatch_queue_t _syncQueue;
    int _count;
    id _result;
    completion_block_t _completionHandler;
    id _self;  // immortality
}

- (id)initWithCount:(int)count completion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _count = count;
        _syncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("op.sync_queue", NULL);
        _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) result {
    __block id result;
    dispatch_sync(_syncQueue, ^{
        result = _result;
    });
    return result;
}

- (void) start
{
    dispatch_async(_syncQueue, ^{
        if (!self.isCancelled && !_isFinished && !_isExecuting) {
            self.isExecuting = YES;
            _self = self; // make self immortal for the duration of the task
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
                
                // Simulated work load:
                int count = _count;
                while (count > 0) {
                    if (self.isCancelled) {
                        break;
                    }
                    printf(".");
                    usleep(100*1000);
                    --count;
                }
                
                // Set result and terminate
                dispatch_async(_syncQueue, ^{
                    if (_result == nil && count == 0) {
                        _result = @"OK";
                    }
                    [self terminate];
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

- (void) terminate {
    self.isExecuting = NO;
    self.isFinished = YES;
    completion_block_t completionHandler = _completionHandler;
    _completionHandler = nil;
    id result = _result;
    _self = nil;
    if (completionHandler) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            completionHandler(result);
        });
    }
}


- (BOOL) isConcurrent {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) isExecuting {
    return _isExecuting;
}
- (void) setIsExecuting:(BOOL)isExecuting {
    if (_isExecuting != isExecuting) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        _isExecuting = isExecuting;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    }
}

- (BOOL) isFinished {
    return _isFinished;
}
- (void) setIsFinished:(BOOL)isFinished {
    if (_isFinished != isFinished) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _isFinished = isFinished;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    }
}

- (void) cancel {
    dispatch_async(_syncQueue, ^{
        if (_result == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Operation cancelled");
            [super cancel];
            _result = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"MyOperation"
                                                 code:-1000
                                             userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"cancelled"}];
        }
    });
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you satisfied that your code is working? Are there problems you need to resolve or is the code ready for a review?

Comment: I'm quite confident that there are no obvious errors. But thread-safity is tricky. So I would appreciate it if you or anybody else can take a look and possibly spot potential issues. ;)  E.g.: dead locks, due to dispatch lib, circular references, etc.

Comment: Why aren't you dispatching on to `_syncQueue` for `terminate` and the setters & getters for `isExecuting` and `isFinished`?  I guess it doesn't matter for `terminate`, since only you access that, but `isExecuting` and `isFinished` could be accessed by a developer from any thread.

Comment: @AaronBrager It's guaranteed by the implementation that `terminate` will be executed on the `_syncQueue`. For properties `isExecuting` and `isFinished`, IMHO synchronization and memory barriers are not required: both are boolean values which are initially set to zero. Any access might return either zero or a non-zero value - which is the value of the corresponding memory location (no register). When a `NO` is returned, its value MUST be treated immediately stale, anyway. It's also guaranteed that the value of the memory location will be eventually set and never changes subsequently.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper That makes sense.  I can find no issues with your implementation.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Shouldn't the `cancel` method set `_isFinished` to `YES` and `_isExecuting ` to `NO` ?

Comment: Specifically, you must change the value returned by isFinished to YES and the value returned by isExecuting to NO. You must make these changes even if the operation was cancelled before it started executing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Jonas Quite late - but yes you are right. I changed the example implementation such that `terminate` will be called even when the operation has been cancelled before it has been started. This ensures that the completion handler will be called in any case, and the operation has proper states.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: Please read: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) to understand what edits can make sense when there are answers to your questions.

Comment: Whether or not this is a problem depends on the semantics you've defined for your NSOperation implementation, but your `executing` and `finished` properties can be in an inconsistent state with respect to each other. In other words, you aren't setting `finished` to YES and `executing` to NO atomically.

Comment: Another latecomer.  But why this requirement? "start shall only start the task once, otherwise it has no effect.".  NSOperation documentation specifically states that they are one-shot so calling start twice on an NSOperation instance is a programmer error.

Comment: @JeremyWiebe If it's a programmer error, how should the implementation deal with this? Perhaps with an `assert`,  or throwing an exception or doing nothing? Of course, this is debatable. IMHO, the implementation should check for preconditions if possible. In this special case an assertion would be fine, too. However, it would have required some means to check whether this method has bee invoked already - even in Debug configuration - and possibly in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 6):

```
- (id)initWithCount:(int)count completion:(completion_block_t)completioHandler;
```

There's a typo here, a missing "n" in the last argument.

---

```
- (id)initWithCount:(int)count completion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler
{

- (id) result {

- (void) start
{
```

This inconsistency is really bothersome to me.  The opening bracket should either be on the same line or the next line, but do it consistently.  Personally, I prefer the opening bracket on the same line as it looks better when the methods are collapsed in Xcode.

---

```
if (!self.isCancelled && !_isFinished && !_isExecuting) {
    self.isExecuting = YES;
```

This inconsistency also bothers me, and it's not immediately clear why it's done.  In fact, even as a season Objective-C programmer, I'm confused as to what would actually happen here when you do `self.isExecuting = YES;`

Normally, you'd do `self.isExecuting = YES;` because you've defined `isExecuting` as a property, and what is actually done is more akin to this:

```
[self setIsExecuting:YES];
```

But you've not defined `isExecuting` as a full property, but rather you've defined `_isExecuting` as an instance variable and created `setIsExecuting:(BOOL)isExecuting` as a method.

I don't rightly know without just running the code what would or should happen here.

So the solution is to either define `isExecuting` as a property so it's more clear what `self.isExecuting = YES;` would actually do, or to change your `self.isExecuting = YES;` to either `_isExecuting = YES;` or `[self setIsExecuting:YES];` depending on the intent.

Comment: The property declarations were indeed missing. Thanks for pointing this to us. Just for information: the dot syntax would still work - but I too prefer to have proper declarations ;)   Then, the invocation of the property setter in the implementation for `isExecuting` and `isFinished` is required in order to fire the KVO notification messages.