# Canonical Implementation for a Concurrent Subclass of NSOperation in Swift 2

Tags: concurrency, swift

I would like to develop a kind of template or canonical implementation for a concurrent subclass of NSOperation in Swift.

See here for my [previous request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36632/canonical-implementation-of-a-subclass-of-nsoperation) which is implemented in Objective-C.
In that previous solution, there are still issues when the operation will be cancelled while it has not yet been started. There is also more or less sloppy approach regarding concurrency when accessing the properties `isExecuting` and `isFinished`.

In this new implementation, using Swift, I also try to address the previous issues.

I appreciate any comments, suggestions and questions.

**Requirements:**

- Thread safe API.
- `start` shall only start the task once, otherwise it should have no effect.
- The operation object should not prematurely deinit while the task is executing.
- Provide a reusable subclass of `NSOperation` that can be easily used as a base class of any custom operation.

**References:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

**Generic class `Operation<T>`:**

Note: The type parameter `T` refers to the type of the calculated value of the underlying asynchronous task. Since the task can also fail, an appropriate "Return type" of such a task is a `Result<T>` which is a discriminated union representing *either* a value of type `T` or an error conforming to protocol `ErrorType`. The `Result<T>` is a Swift `enum`.

```
import Foundation


public enum OperationError : Int, ErrorType {
    case Cancelled = -1
    case NoTask = -1000
}



private var queue_ID_key = 0

public class Operation<T> : NSOperation {

    public typealias ValueType = T
    public typealias ResultType = Result<ValueType>
    public typealias ContinuationFunc = ResultType -> ()

    private var _result: Result<ValueType>?
    private let _syncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("operation.sync_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    private var _isExecuting = false
    private var _isFinished = false
    private var _continuation: ContinuationFunc?
    private var _self: NSOperation? = nil

    public required init(continuation: ContinuationFunc? = nil) {
        let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<dispatch_queue_t>.passUnretained(_syncQueue).toOpaque())
        dispatch_queue_set_specific(_syncQueue, &queue_ID_key, context, nil)
        _continuation = continuation
    }

    /**
    Override in subclass
    `task` will be called within the synchronization context. The completion handler
    should be called on a private execution context.
    */
    public func task(completion: ResultType -> ()) {
        assert(true, "override in subclass")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
            completion(Result(error: OperationError.NoTask))
        }
    }


    public final override var asynchronous : Bool  { return true }

    public final override var executing : Bool {
        get {
            // Note: `executing` will be called recursively from `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`. Thus, we need a counter measurement to prevent a deadlock:
            if is_synchronized() {
                return _isExecuting
            }
            var result = false
            dispatch_sync(_syncQueue) {
                result = self._isExecuting
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            dispatch_async(_syncQueue) {
                if self._isExecuting != newValue {
                    self.willChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
                    self._isExecuting = newValue
                    self.didChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public final override var finished : Bool {
        get {
            // Note: `finished` will be called recursively from `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`. Thus, we need a counter measurement to prevent a deadlock:
            if is_synchronized() {
                return _isFinished
            }
            var result = false
            dispatch_sync(_syncQueue) {
                result = self._isFinished
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            dispatch_async(_syncQueue) {
                if self._isFinished != newValue {
                    self.willChangeValueForKey("isFinished")
                    self._isExecuting = newValue
                    self.didChangeValueForKey("isFinished")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
        Returns the result of the operation.
    */
    public final var result: ResultType? {
        var result: ResultType? = nil
        dispatch_sync(_syncQueue) {
            result = self._result;
        }
        return result;
    }


    /**
        Starts the operation.
        `start` has no effect when the operation has been cancelled, or when it
        has already been started.
    */
    public final override func start()  {
        dispatch_async(_syncQueue) {
            if !self.cancelled && !self._isFinished && !self._isExecuting {
                self.executing = true;
                self._self = self; // make self immortal for the duration of the task
                self.task() { result in
                    dispatch_async(self._syncQueue) {
                        self._result = result
                        self.terminate()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
        `terminate` will be called when `self` has been cancelled or when `self`'s task
        completes. Sets its `finished` property to `true`.
        If there is a continuation it will be called. If self has a `completionBlock`
        it will be called, too.
    */
    private final func terminate() {
        assert(_result != nil)
        if _isExecuting {
            self.executing = false
        }
        self.finished = true
        if let continuation = _continuation {
            _continuation = nil
            let result = _result
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
                continuation(result!)
            }
        }
        _self = nil
    }

    /**
        Asynchronously requests a cancellation.
        If the operation has been cancelled already or if it is finished, the
        method has no effect. Otherwise, calls `super.cancel()`, sets the result to
       `OperationError.Cancelled` and sets the `finished` property to `true`. If the 
        operation is executing it sets the `executing` property to `false`. If there
        is a continuation, it will be called with the operation's result as its
        argument.
    */
    public final override func cancel() {
        dispatch_async(_syncQueue) {
            // Cancel should not have an effect if self is already cancelled, or self has been finished.
            // We test `_result` to accomplish this:
            if self._result == nil {
                self._result = Result(error: OperationError.Cancelled)
                super.cancel()
                self.terminate()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
        Returns `true` if the current execution context is synchronized with
        the `_syncQueue`.
    */
    private final func is_synchronized() -> Bool {
        let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<dispatch_queue_t>.passUnretained(_syncQueue).toOpaque())
        return dispatch_get_specific(&queue_ID_key) == context
    }


}
```

(The implementation for class `Result<T>` is not shown)

**Sample Custom Class:**

```
public class MyOperation : Operation<String> {        
    private var _duration = 1.0        

    public required init(continuation: ContinuationFunc? = nil) {
        super.init(continuation: continuation)
    }

    public init(duration: Double, continuation: ContinuationFunc? = nil) {
        _duration = duration
        super.init(continuation: continuation)
    }

    public override func task(completion: ResultType -> ()) {
        let delay: Double = _duration
        let t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(t, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
            completion(Result("OK"))
        }
    }

}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
func testOperationShoudlCompleteWithSuccess() {
    let expect1 = self.expectationWithDescription("continuation1 should be called")
    let op = MyOperation() { result in
        expect1.fulfill()
    }
    op.start()

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(2, handler: nil)
}


func testStartedOperationShoudlCompleteWithCancellationError() {
    let expect1 = self.expectationWithDescription("continuation1 should be called")
    let op = MyOperation() { result in
        do {
            let _ = try result.value()
            XCTFail("unexpected success")
        }
        catch let error {
            XCTAssertTrue(error is OperationError)
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        expect1.fulfill()
    }
    op.start()
    op.cancel()

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(2, handler: nil)
}


func testScheduledOperationsShouldCompleteWithSuccess() {

    let expectations = [
        self.expectationWithDescription("continuation1 should be called"),
        self.expectationWithDescription("continuation2 should be called"),
        self.expectationWithDescription("continuation3 should be called"),
    ]

    let operations = [
        MyOperation(duration: 0.1) { result in
            XCTAssertTrue(result.isSuccess)
            expectations[0].fulfill()
        },
        MyOperation(duration: 0.1) { result in
            XCTAssertTrue(result.isSuccess)
            expectations[1].fulfill()
        },
        MyOperation(duration: 0.1) { result in
            XCTAssertTrue(result.isSuccess)
            expectations[2].fulfill()
        }            
    ]

    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(0.4, handler: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is good and I've tried something similar before, but if I wanted the result to be a tuple type, as of now the generics approach just won't work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you made a typo in the setter of finished.

You have `self._isExecuting = newValue` instead of `self._isFinished = newValue`.

When we wait for operations to finish, this typo will cause it to hang.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job spotting your first bug!

Comment: Nice spot! Yes, this is an error. Thank you very much for reporting! I've made a couple of improvements to this class in some other test code. But due to the complexity of subclasses that NSOperation requires and also due to other limitations  - I'm not using NSOperations anymore in production, instead using alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Weak self inside closures to avoid memory issues.

Also, provide memory referencing for optimal memory handling.

Please update to the latest swift version

Comment: Given that this question was asked 4 years and 4 months ago, there is really no good reason to update to the latest version of swift.